# Add a predefined struct type to an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have defined a structure for users as USER:

```
struct user {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

typedef struct user USER;
```

And I can create an array of users:

```
USER uArray[3] = {
    { "Allan", 12 },
    { "Bob", 34 },
    { "Chris", 56 }
};
```

Now how do I go about adding a predefined user to a list of users?:

```
USER u1 = { "Dave", 78 };
```

I assumed that you could just add it to the list as followed. However, an error is returned, stating that it cannot convert from 'USER' to 'char*'.

```
USER uArray[4] = {
    { "Allan", 12 },
    { "Bob", 34 },
    { "Chris", 56 },
    u1
};
```

I understand that its treating u1 as the first element of creating a user (name = u1) so how else can you add a predefined user to an array of users?

---

The code is now working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct user {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

typedef struct user USER;

void changeName(USER *u);

void main(void)
{
    USER u1 = { "Dave", 78 };

    USER uArray[4] = {
            { "Allan", 12 },
            { "Bob", 34 },
            { "Chris", 56 }
    };

    // add u1 to position 3 of the array
    uArray[3] = u1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (uArray[i].name == "Bob")
        {
            changeName(&uArray[i]);
        }
        printf("User: %d, Name: %s, Age: %d\n", i, uArray[i].name, uArray[i].age);
    }
}

void changeName(USER *u)
{
    u->name = "Dave";
}
```

Comment: That adds it to the array, but when executed, it returns a debug error; stating that the stack around the variable (both uArray and u1) was corrupted.

Comment: use C99 Compiler. E.g clang, gcc.

Comment: Is it something to do with the compiler? I mean should the provided solution work?

Comment: @Kurtiss  variable can be used in the initialization since c99.(except in the case of like global variable)

Comment: Do you have braces around the `u1` in your code? That would at least explain the error about converting from `USER` to `char`. The stack corruption happens probably elsewhere, so you should post more code. (If the program is large, try to isolate the error in a few lines and post only these.)

Comment: @MOehm the code can now be viewed within the question.

Comment: `if (uArray[i].name == "Bob")` : It is not necessarily to operate as expected.

Comment: @BLEPIXY its just me experimenting the C language. I just wanted to see if I could alter a specific user from the list using pointers.

Comment: [C99 demo](http://ideone.com/t1oy4p)

Comment: I think better it is to implement something like a linked list or  vector if you are thinking of adding elements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 to run my C files so I'm currently unsure on what to do in order to use C99. Also, I'm aware of what linked lists are; how would they benefit over arrays in terms of adding elements?

Comment: @Kurtiss VS2013 has achieved some of the C99, but not all. It is executable [Paul R's DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/364d4b4409a3ca2c) You can use the C++(VC++) as compiler. The advantage of using a linked list is that the cost of the additional elements is low if it is not determined by the number of elements. But it is not suitable for random access.

Comment: It sounds like arrays are very static in the C language (not considering C++ or C#).

Comment: the Array in C, It may be considered that size of array can not be changed at a fixed size. (Same in VLA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #include <stdio.h>

   struct user {
      char *name;
      int age;
   };

   typedef struct user USER;

  USER u1 = { "Dave", 78 };

  USER uArray[4] = {
     { "Allan", 12 },
     { "Bob", 34 },
     { "Chris", 56 }
  };

  int main()
  {

     int i;

     uArray[3] = u1;
     for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
     {
        printf("%s: %d\n", uArray[i].name, uArray[i].age);
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: That adds it to the array, but when executed, it returns a debug error; stating that the stack around the variable (both uArray and u1) was corrupted.

Comment: I compiled and got proper output.
cc <filename.c> -o f1
./f1

Comment: Ok its been fixed, however the solution confuses me; when the array is defined, you have to specify the maximum number of users allowed within the array (4) but to add the predefined user to the array, you have to specify how many users the array is currently holding (3) and not only that, but it looks like the solution states that the array is equal to the user, where in fact, its just adding the user to the list, wth?

Comment: @Kurtiss: That's C for you. You should probably keep a count of active users alongside the array and take care not to overflow the array. By the way, `uArray[3] = u1` does quite explicitly assign the user `u1` to the fourth entry (with index `3`) of the array of users. It doesn't say that the array is equal to the user.

Comment: I just realised that now >< so it's assigning the user to that specific point within the array (position 3 in this case), sorry, I can be so stupid sometimes.